# How to switch between overlapping uipanels in Matlab GUI (Matlab2016)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I made a GUI with two uipanels, each containing 4 image axes.

I plotted different figures on each panel and want to switch between panels by a push button.

For this I used the following:

Initially, I set `uipanel2` to 'visible' 'on' and `uipanel3` to 'visible' 'off';

Then when I push 'push button' it checks if uipanel is 'on' and turns on and off respectively.

```
% Code:
set(handles.uipanel2,'visible','on');
set(handles.uipanel3,'visible','off');
% When I push 'push button':
if  strcmp(get(handles.uipanel2,'visible'),'on')
    disp('panel-2 onn switching it off')
    set(handles.uipanel2,'visible','off');
    set(handles.uipanel3,'visible','on');
elseif strcmp(get(handles.uipanel3,'visible'),'on')
    disp('panel-3 onn switching it off')
    set(handles.uipanel3,'visible','off');
    set(handles.uipanel2,'visible','on');
end
```

It doesn't work as expected I don't see panels switching.
For displaying images I used code like this:

```
% Panel-2
axes(handles.RCC);
imshow(img_RCC,lims);
axes(handles.LCC);
imshow(img_LCC,lims);
axes(handles.RML);
imshow(img_RML,lims);
axes(handles.LML);
imshow(img_LML,lims);
% Panel-3
axes(handles.RCC_Orig);
imshow(img_RCC,lims);
axes(handles.LCC_Orig);
imshow(img_LCC,lims);
axes(handles.RML_Orig);
imshow(img_RML,lims);
axes(handles.LML_Orig);
imshow(img_LML,lims);
```

**Update:** I can only see the GUI panel on top being 'not visible' and switching to 'visible'. The panel on bottom I think is still there but I don't know how to make it come on top

Comment: Have you considered using `uitab`?

Comment: I have no idea of it, is it useful for this kind of panel switching, can you give  an example of how it is used for panel switching

Comment: Read the documentation for it. You create a `uitabgroup` and then `uitab` objects (which are just `uipanels`) and then use the tab to switch between the two.

Comment: Is there a button on guide window to create uitabgroup?

Comment: I don't believe so, you'll have to create it programmatically in your `OpeningFcn`

Comment: I have a total of 8 figure axes and I think uitabgroup without GUIDE will make it more complicated and I have to start from scrath, Is there anyway to use my code above to use a push button to offer such feature

Comment: You haven't provided enough code for us to diagnose the issue.

Comment: I figured out that my uipanel3 is within the uipanel2 and when I made them seperate it worked as expected. Thanks for your suggestions I will use uitabs next time when I start a new GUI